# Delete first k entries from table in java sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to expire old entries from my sqlite db using the following code (which is scala, but closely analogous to java code):

```
  val c = DriverManager.getConnection(
    s"jdbc:sqlite:my_data.db")
  c.setAutoCommit(false)

  val deleteQuery = c.prepareStatement(
    """delete from my_table
      | where id != ?
      | order by id
      | limit ?
      | """.stripMargin)
  deleteQuery.setInt(1, specialId)
  deleteQuery.setInt(2, maxNumRecords / 2)
  logger.info(s"executing delete query: $deleteQuery")
  val dr = deleteQuery.executeUpdate()
  deleteQuery.close()
  logger.info(s"finished executing delete query: $dr $deleteQuery")

  logger.info("committing db queries")
  c.commit()
  logger.info("finished committing db queries")
  c.close()
```

However, I receive the following exception at the call to `prepareStatement`:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "order": syntax error)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:868)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:211)
    at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:40)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:29)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:18)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:251)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:223)
```

Maybe I'm missing something simple, but running this in the `sqlite3` command line seems to work:

```
sqlite> select id from my_table limit 20;
1
2
3
...
sqlite> delete from my_table where id != 2 order by id limit 5;
sqlite> select id from my_table limit 20;
2
6
7
...
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: Is that extra 's' character in the `DriverManager.getConnection()` argument also in your source code?

Comment: Yes, I edited my local path, which is using scala string interpolation to compute the path. It's irrelevant for the behavior, other queries work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY for DELETE is [not enabled by default](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

You can always determine the rows to delete with a subquery:

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM my_table
             WHERE id != ?
             ORDER BY id
             LIMIT ?)
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to enable it without recompiling the java driver? I guess it works from the command line because `sqlite3` has the feature enabled in the package I installed.

Comment: That option is called a compile-time option because it must be set a compile time. (And the default `sqlite3` does not enable it either; I wonder where you got yours.)